# After creation of Junit test cases, the "Run as Junit Test" disappears

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

I had made a Junit Test case using menu options in Eclipse.
I was getting the option "Run as JUnit Test".
But when I was done with my changes, I noticed that the "Run as JUnit Test" disappeared.

On further analysis I found that my initially my TestClass definition was as below :

```
public class SampleTest
{
....
}
```

But I had to change the class definition to follows

```
public class SampleTest<T>   
{
..
}
```

So what I noticed was adding the generic was creating the behavior.
I looked at the following links:

[Run As JUnit not appearing in Eclipse - using JUnit4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149882/run-as-junit-not-appearing-in-eclipse-using-junit4)

[Missing "Run as JUnit Test"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365920/missing-run-as-junit-test)

```
public class SampleTest<T>
{
..
}
```

But these links are less related to my issue.
So, I need to understand the reason what including Generics has to do with the behavior.

Comment: Why do you want to use generic in your test class? When are you going to define its type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running a JUnit test class Eclipse needs to

1. create an instance of your test class by calling its default constructor,
2. call all the `@Test` methods on that instance

Here the problem is in step 1: Eclipse doesn't know which type `T` to use in the constructor.
Should it use `new SampleTest<Object>()`
or `new SampleTest<WhatEver>()`?
So it decides that it is not a valid JUnit test class
and doesn't offer the *Run as JUnit Test* option.

Comment: I think it is a valid explanation, because as there is no way to deduce that the class is a valid JUnit test case.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be able to add much as to why Generics would remove JUnit from starting, but usually test classes act as a wrapper to test a specific class, such as:

```
public class Sample<T>
{
    ...
}

public class SampleTest
{

    Sample<TypeHere> sample;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }
        sample= new Sample<OrTypeHere>(...);
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void whenConditionOne_verifyExpectedSituation() throws Exception {

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)` before your test class is optional when `JUnit3` tests are not present in your test class, this is something I noticed just a little while ago, but may help in forcing tests to be of `JUnit4`